# Casting [Int] to [Double] from input

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a list of constants and degrees of a polynomial equation and want to return a list of this composition for a value be applied and then summed. But this list comes as Int and my function expects a list of double.

```
poly :: [Double] -> [Double] -> [Double -> Double]
poly a b =
  let f x y = (*x) . (**y)
        in uncurry f <$> zip a b

-- does not work
poly ([1,2,3]:: [Double]) ([1,2,3]:: [Double])
```

How to cast a list of int to list of double?

Comment: `poly = zipWith $ \x y -> (*x) . (**y)` is a simpler way to write that function

Comment: @4castle with your answer and @Victoria Ruiz I could solve, thx the final form is ```poly = zipWith $ \x y -> (* (fromIntegral x)) . (** (fromIntegral y))```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`fromIntegral`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=fromIntegral), which will convert from any Integral type into any Numeric type (Int, Integer, Rational, and Double).

More here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Converting_numbers

Answer (score 0):

With @4castle and Victoria Ruiz I came up with the following:

```
poly :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Double -> Double]
poly = zipWith $ \x y -> (* (fromIntegral x)) . (** (fromIntegral y))

apply ::  Double -> [Double -> Double] -> Double
apply x b = sum $ ($x) <$> b
-- l=left limiting, r=right limiting, a=coeficients, b=degrees
solve :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Double]
solve l r a b =
  let h        = 0.001
      linspace = [fromIntegral l,fromIntegral l+h..fromIntegral r]
      p = poly a b
      area = sum $ map ((*h) . (`apply` p)) linspace
      volume = h * (sum $ map ((*pi) . (**2) .(`apply` p)) linspace)
  in [area,volume]
```

I think Haskell compiler with his strong type inference has some peculiarities that can't be directly solved by type cast.